# RWeka won't load. Using RStudio

Tags: java, r, rweka

library(RWeka) gives this error:

Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Users/Richard/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/rJava/R/rJava.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RWeka’

I have also updated Java.  I am using Windows 10 and RStudio.

I have removed.packages("rJava") and ("RWeka").  Then I installed.packages("rJava") and ("RWeka"). Still getting this message.

Comment: Can you load the rJava package on it's own?

Comment: Yes, no error after install.packages("rJava") or install.packages("RWeka").  The errors are seen after:                          > library(RWeka)
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Users/Richard/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/rJava/R/rJava.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RWeka’

Comment: If anyone can help I would appreciate it.  I have removed and reinstalled both rJava and RWeka.  They both install.  The problem is when I use library(RWeka) or library(RWeka) I get error message (see above).  If RWeka does not work, I have to figure out something equivalent to the OneR method.

Comment: Use the OneR packages for the OneR method.